# Como fazer o parse de um array de string para um array multidimensional?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => MemTotal:        4060964 kB
    [1] => MemFree:         3630320 kB
    [2] => MemAvailable:    3789472 kB
    [3] => Buffers:           93040 kB
    [4] => SwapCached:            0
    [6] => Active:           306312 kB
)
```

Preciso reescrever este array de modo que fique assim:

```
Array
(
    [MemTotal]     => 4060964 kB
    [MemFree]      => 3630320 kB
    [MemAvailable] => 3789472 kB
    [Buffers]      =>   93040 kB
    [SwapCached]   =>       0
)
```

As regras seriam:

1. O índice é tudo que vier antes de dois-pontos (:)
2. O conteúdo é precedido por dois-pontos e uma sequência de um ou mais caracteres de espaços

Como fazer este parse?

Answer (score 6):

Utilize `explode()` para separar a chave (`$str[0]`) e o valor (`$str[1]`) de cada item do array, após basta combinar o par e atribuir esse elemento no array novo.

```
$arr = ['MemTotal:        4060964 kB',
        'MemFree:         3630320 kB',
        'MemAvailable:    3789472 kB',
        'Buffers:           93040 kB',
        'SwapCached:            0',
        'Active:           306312 kB'];

$novo = array();
foreach($arr as $item){
    $str = explode(':', $item);
    $novo[$str[0]] = trim($str[1]); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Nesse exemplo, mantive o mesmo objeto.

Os índices originais são removidos conforme são "convertidos"

```
$arr = array(
    'a:     1',
    'b: 4',
    'c:   2',
);

print_r($arr);

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $a = explode(':', $v);
    $arr[$a[0]] = trim($a[1]);
    unset($arr[$k]);
}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilize [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) dentro de uma interação (`for`) varrendo cada linha e transformado em outro `array`:

```
$dados = array
(
    0 => 'MemTotal:        4060964 kB',
    1 => 'MemFree:         3630320 kB',
    2 => 'MemAvailable:    3789472 kB',
    3 => 'Buffers:           93040 kB',
    4 => 'SwapCached:            0',
    6 => 'Active:           306312 kB'
);


$dadosNew = array();
foreach($dados as $key => $value)
{
    $valueNew = explode(":", $value);
    $dadosNew[$valueNew[0]] = trim($valueNew[1]);
}

var_dump($dadosNew);
```

[***Exemplo***](http://ideone.com/z4sn0x)

Comment: Foi o único que pegou no exemplo dado +1.